# The console gives me " No goals have been specified for this build"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to run my first spring boot application however the console gives me an error saying that "No goals have been specified for this build"
below is the console error, also I'm not sure if the tomcat server will run or not.
The last thing, why the console didn't return "Spring" logo

```
C:\Users\mmaksoud\.jdks\openjdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\mmaksoud\Desktop\demo "-Dmaven.home=D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=53196:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2020.1
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.135 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-17T16:44:51+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

Comment: How did you run nmaven?

Comment: You will have to pass a [Maven goal](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) to compile and/or run. For running the Spring Boot app with Maven, you can use ```mvn spring-boot:run```

Comment: @PieterjanDeconinck I used this command and the console returned "No plugin found for prefix "Spring-boot" in the current project

Comment: Then you are missing something in your POM file. Do you have ```spring-boot-starter-parent``` listed as parent? And ```spring-boot-maven-plugin``` as a build plugin? FYI, you can create a new project using https://start.spring.io/, which will make sure you have the correct configuration.

Comment: yes I'm sure, and I did user spring initializer web site @PieterjanDeconinck 
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

Comment: oh solved now, thank you very much @PieterjanDeconinck. I was looking to another directory.

Comment: is there a way to make it run by just clicking the "Run" icon in the ide

Comment: Yes, you can add custom run configurations in IntelliJ, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html#